# Actionscript 3, access Symbol properties (AS Linkage)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, class, actionscript, movieclip

I have created a new Symbol in the `Flash IDE`, I set it to Export for `Actionscript` and it has a class name of `itemCoin`

My stage has now 3 movieclips of that class, how can I:

- count how many of `itemCoin` are on the stage
- manipulate them, set and get their x, y individually etc. I tried `itemCoin[0].x` [1] [2]...etc but it throws an error
- remove them from stage when needed
- add an event listener that executes a function whenever a `itemCoin` is removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instance name is used for referencing instances of objects.

For example, if you had a symbol of type `ItemCoin` (note that naming convention for a type usually starts with a capital letter):

[image: symbols]

When you place instances on the stage, you give them an instance name to reference them by (note that naming convention for an instance is usually camel case):

[image: instance-name]

Now, properties may be accessed by referencing the instance name from code:

```
itemCoin1.x = 50;
itemCoin1.y = 25;
```

Remove it form stage:

```
removeChild(itemCoin1);
```

Add an event listener to the itemCoin1 instance for when it is removed:

```
import flash.events.Event;

itemCoin1.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, removedHandler);

function removedHandler(event:Event):void {
    trace("itemCoin1 was removed");
}

removeChild(itemCoin1);
```

Although generally a poor practice, you can iterate all children to identify instances.  For example, to count the number of ItemCoins:

```
import flash.display.DisplayObject;

var count:uint = 0;

for (var i:uint = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
    var obj:DisplayObject = getChildAt(i);

    if (obj is ItemCoin) {
        trace("Found " + ++count + " item coins so far.");
    }
}
```

To comprehensively search the display list, you'd have to traverse children of all display objects.

If knowing the total number of instances on the stage was that important, it might be a better idea to define some ActionScript inside the component or within a Factory class to reference count when added to stage and removed from stage.

Comment: Thank you, the last method was what I needed, I used an array to store the instance IDs. I suppose this is as efficient as it can go working from within the IDE and not using .as Classes.